# Calculate the flux of the vector field $\vec F(x,y,z)= (x-y-4)\vec i+y\vec j +z\vec k$ across the superior semi-sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: calculus

Calculate the flux of the  vector field $\vec F(x,y,z)= (x-y-4)\vec i+y\vec j +z\vec k$ across the superior semi-sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, with a field of normal vectors $\vec n$ such that $\langle\vec n, \vec k\rangle > 0$

Answer: $2\pi$

My attempt:

The most convenient vector that could satisfy the given condition that I could think of was

$\vec n=(0,0,1)$

Using the definition of flux as the dot product between the field and it's normal vector  we would have

$\int\int_S\langle\vec F,\vec n\rangle dS=\int\int_SzdS$

Writing the surface in spherical coordinates that fits it's description we have

$\vec r(\phi,\theta)=(\sin\phi\cos\theta,\sin\phi\sin\theta,\cos\phi), 0\leq\phi\leq\pi/2,0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$

And it's element of area is already known as

$dS=\sin\phi d\theta d\phi$

Combining all the results above we have

$\int\int_SzdS=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\phi\sin\phi d\theta d\phi=\pi$

I'm not so sure if my pick for the normal vectors makes sense, since I usually put the surface in a parametric equation first, calculate the vector product between the partial derivatives of the parameters and later on I choose the orientation, but doing that on this problem seems more hard, beyond that everything looks fine for me. What was my mistake here?

Comment: What's the reason for downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps the current downvote is because you didn't explain your reasoning behind your attempt. A bunch of mathematical symbols without commentary is not very informative.

Comment: Have you considered using the divergence theorem to "switch the surface" to the closed unit disc $x^2+y^2\leq 1,z=0$?

Comment: @MatthewH. It's something that I plan to do later, first I want to feel confident using this definition of flux, so I need to understand what my mistakes are.

Comment: $\langle0,0,1\rangle$ is not normal to the sphere at every point on the sphere, only at the point $(0,0,1)$, hence the surface integral doesn't reduce to just the contribution of the $\vec k$ term. Consider instead$$\vec n=\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\phi}\times\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\theta}$$(or its negative, if this happens to have to wrong orientation)

Comment: @user170231 doing that we would have $\vec n = \sin^2\phi\cos\theta\vec i +\sin^2\phi\sin\theta\vec j+\sin\phi\cos\phi\vec k$ to met the condition we would need that $\sin\phi\cos\phi > 0$. I'm not sure what this implies, what I could think is that $\phi$ needs to give both $\sin$ and $\cos$ positive or negative so one possible bound would be $0\leq\phi\leq\phi/2$ but that got me $\pi^2$ as the result.